# DateTimerPicker VBA

Tags: vb.net

Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação em Visual Basic, e gostaria de saber como carregar horas salvas no banco de dados para o controle `DateTimePicker`, consigo inserir normalmente o valor no banco de dados.

```
Format(TimeOfDay.ToString("HH:mm:ss"))
```

mas não consigo recuperar o valor no controle.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Revirando o MSDN Descobri!

```
 Dim h As New TimeSpan
 h = bs_coleta.Current("coleta_horaColeta")
 DateTimePicker1.text = h.ToString
```

bs_coleta é um BindingSource que armazena temporariamente os dados da tabela Coleta.